# Facebook App invites iOS integration error

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

When I try to open Facebook App invite using below code, my app crashes with reason: `-[NSTaggedPointerString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/565305550289696"];
//optionally set previewImageURL
content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2015/holidays-2015-day-3-6399865393250304.2-res.png"];

// present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:shareAlertController withContent:content delegate:self];
```

I did all setup mentioned on Facebook Developer websites, also created proper Applink.

What can be the reason for this error?

Comment: You should try acting Exception breakpoint as mentioned in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802942/656600 that will give you the exact like where it is crashing. Them may be we cab figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in info plist with array type. Just right click `Info.plist` and **Open as Source code**. And add below code in it.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```